# Module not found: Can't resolve './Base'

Tags: reactjs, windows, macos, npm

Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Base' in yadayadayada\src

So, I'm on my Windows 10 PC trying to npm start a project that was initially setup on Mac OS. I have no problems ever, cloning the project repo and compiling the project on my mac. All I have to do is npm install and it just works.

I don't have a webpack config file and I've never heard of that stuff until I started googling this issue. I deleted my package-lock.json and did npm install to no luck. I also don't see a freakin .Base folder anywhere so idk what's going on.

Comment: Could you add the content of your `.src/index.js` file?

Comment: If your index.js file import from './Base' it can mean one of five things: `Base` folder or `Base.js` or `Base.jsx` or `Base.ts` or `Base.tsx` file within the same catalog that your index.js file is

Comment: I ended up fixing this. I had to just run the program on my Linux machine.